# Adding row to gridview using button in c# winform and sql server

Tags: c#, sql, winforms, listview, gridview

I am working on project about student grading system. I am stucked the point that ı will be showing below:

```
STUDENT ID : 12345
STUDENT NAME : ALEXIA

LESSONS :          GRADE 1     GRADE 2  AVERAGE   LIMIT    RESULT
PHYSICS             40          80         60      50        PASS
CALCULUS            20          10         15      50        FAIL
Add new lesson

New list should be ; (assume we add Sport as new lesson on the list)

    LESSONS :          GRADE 1     GRADE 2  AVERAGE   LIMIT    RESULT
     PHYSICS             40          80         60      50        PASS
     CALCULUS            20          10         15      50        FAIL
     SPORT               100         100       100      50        PASS
    add new lesson (line)
```

I will save such data to database then list all data on new form as;

```
  STUDENT NAME : ALEXIA

  LESSONS          GRADE          RESULT
   PHYSICS           60             PASS
   CALCULUS          15             FAIL
   SPORT            100             PASS
```

How I can develop such structure here . May I need to use grid or list

Advices will really be appreciated

Comment: Doesn't matter. Both `ListView` and `DataGridView` can be used in your case

Comment: Can you please give me code example

Comment: Google will find you a very large  supply of examples for both a grid and a list.  We shouldn't need to do your research for you.

Comment: @cdkMoose can you please share link with me so ı can check

Comment: You can find Google at http://www.google.com.  We aren't here to do your research for you.  If you can type a question here, I think you can type a question on Google.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for something so simple as add new row to gridview by pression a button and some textbox or something try this

```
DataGridViewRow row = (DataGridViewRow)yourDataGridView.Rows[0].Clone();
row.Cells["LESSONS"].Value = yourtextbox.text;
row.Cells["Grade"].Value = yourtextbox1.text;
row.Cells["Result"].Value = yourtextbox1.text;
yourDataGridView.Rows.Add(row);
```

Answer (score 0):

1st would like to apologize for miss reading , now that i see is is in winforms just right click on your project in the solution explorer and choose 'Add new User Control'. This will actually let you pick from a number of different kinds of objects to add, but user controls is the one you want. When you add the User Control it should give you a new designer window with a panel all by itself onto which you can drop regular controls. If you then go back to your form you'll see a new section in the toolbox that includes your new control. You can use it just like any other control, including dynamically creating and adding it to a flowlayoutpanel on your form.

Then add a row on datagrid for example as simple as this

```
public DataTable GetResultsTable()
{
    DataTable table = new DataTable();
    table.Columns.Add("Name".ToString());
    table.Columns.Add("Color".ToString());
    DataRow dr = table.NewRow();
    dr["Lesson"] = "Programing";
    dr["Calculus"] = "99";
   dr["result"] = "pass";
    table.Rows.Add(dr);
    return table;
}
public void gridview()
{          
    datagridview1.DataSource =  GetResultsTable();
}
```

Hope this time i helped you go in the right way mate, good luck

Answer (score -1):

I dont know if my this is what you pretend but, lets see..

For what i could understand you want something like this

```
STUDENT NAME : ALEXIA

  LESSONS          GRADE          RESULT
   PHYSICS           60             PASS
   CALCULUS          15             FAIL
   SPORT            100             PASS
```

So you basicly can create one html table structure and use

> <%#      (DataBinder.Eval(Container, "DataItem.username")) %>
>   To bind your items from DB

Now answering your possible questions:

**But i want 3 , 4 or 100 structures like this depending the number of stundes i get from db.**
 Easy mate, put ur structure in a repeater and just assing the datasource to the repeater and you will get the structure according to the data.

**But i dont have only physics, calculus or sport i can add more .**

Just use another repater inside repeater with something like  this

```
<td> <%#(DataBinder.Eval(Container, "DataItem.Title")) %></td><td> <%#(DataBinder.Eval(Container, "DataItem.Grade")) %></td><td> <%#(DataBinder.Eval(Container, "DataItem.Result")) %></td>
```

* PS: remember the dataiitems i use are just example...

Problem accessing repeater inside repeater? Use something like this

```
 protected void Repeater1_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
{
    var data = ((MyClass)e.Item.DataItem).Subcategories;
    var repeater2 = (Repeater)e.Item.FindControl("Repeater2");
    repeater2.DataSource = data;
    repeater2.DataBind();
}
```

Dont know if it was this what you where looking for, but hope it helps in any way. Good luck

Comment: you answer about `ASP.NET`. Question is about `Winforms`

Comment: @Romero it is winforms not ASP.NET . If you have solution in Winforms share with me pls